# Clarify few doubts in connectycube Flutter chat sdk

Tags: connectycube

We are developing a Flutter app with one to one chat, so the user is able to sign up with phone number, email, Google sign-in, Facebook sign-in, Apple sign in. So, regarding the chat we like to clarify few doubts from your development team:

1. How do you maintain the uniqueness for each user like auto-generating user-id?
2. Are we able to change the name of the users before chatting to the opponent?
3. Are we able to change the notification sound, Can we manage the notification with our own notification(we are using awesome notification flutter)?
4. Is there an API available to get the chat history for each user?

Answer (score 2):

1. After getting the correct request for signup (https://developers.connectycube.com/flutter/authentication-and-users?id=user-signup) ConnectyCube's server creates a new user and generates an id for it, and returns newly created user in the response.
2. User can change their name any time via ‘Update profile’ https://developers.connectycube.com/flutter/authentication-and-users?id=user-profile-update request. The only current user can update the user’s name.
3. ConnectyCube SDK doesn’t provide any UI solutions. You can use any plugin(s) for displaying the notifications.
4. The user can fetch only chat history related to this user (https://developers.connectycube.com/flutter/messaging?id=chat-history).

The ConnectyCube has an API for login via Facebook, Firebase phone auth, e-mail, but for Google sign-in and Apple sign in you have to develop your own logic for creating a user and signup it on the ConnectyCube server.